# Circular divs with vertically aligned text and subtitles

Tags: html, css, web

I feel like this is really obvious but I couldn't seem to find any answers on here.

I'm trying to make 5 circular divs, inline, with a letter in the middle representing a grade. I then want the subject title below the grade (but still inside the circle).

[image: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.]

Here's what I've written so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="subject">A</div>
<div class="subject">B</div>
<div class="subject">C</div>
<div class="subject">D</div>
<div class="subject">E</div>
```

CSS:

```
.subject {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
```

Also, I couldn't seem to horizontally center the circles using:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

```css
.subject {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="subject">A</div>
<div class="subject">B</div>
<div class="subject">C</div>
<div class="subject">D</div>
<div class="subject">E</div>
```

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `div`'s in a container and add `text-align: center` to it.

Use pseudo element `:after` to insert the subtitle. Check below example

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.subject {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.subject:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  content: attr(data-sub);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subject" data-sub="Maths">A</div>
  <div class="subject" data-sub="French">B</div>
  <div class="subject" data-sub="Biology">C</div>
  <div class="subject" data-sub="German">D</div>
  <div class="subject" data-sub="Chemistry">E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do follows, i created another div and added `text-align:center` property.Now these group of circles are horizontally centered.

```css
.subject {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
  font-size: 100px;}

.circle{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<div class="subject">A</div>
<div class="subject">B</div>
<div class="subject">C</div>
<div class="subject">D</div>
<div class="subject">E</div></div>
```